# Resizing an image in a picturebox so it always prints 3.5"x2" on any printer?

Tags: vb.net, image, printing, visual-studio-2005, picturebox

I'm using VB.NET (winforms) to print an image in a picturebox.
The picturebox is sized to 525x300.

I can easily resize this with a call to ScaleTransform().

But what should I resize it to?

I need the final printed image to be 3.5" x 2" on any printer.  (A business card size.)

I assume that I need the resolution of the user's printer (I assume everyone's different.)
How do I get that?

And what would be the value I need for ScaleTransform() call?

Thanks.

Update:  I got the printer resolution (300x300) but how would I use that to resize the image so it would ALWAYS print 3.5" x 2.0" on any printer?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to obtain the resolutions supported by a printer installed on the system, you can use the `PrinterSettings` class, which provides a [`PrinterResolutions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printerresolutions.aspx) property. That returns a collection of all the resolutions that are supported by the printer, represented by [`PrinterResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution.aspx) objects. Each of those `PrinterResolution` objects have [`X`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printerresolution.x.aspx) and [`Y`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printerresolution.y.aspx) properties that you can use to obtain the actual horizontal and vertical resolutions in dots per inch (dpi).

But since you're actually *doing* the printing, you should already have access to a [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) object that has a [`PrinterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printersettings.aspx) property. If so, this is the one that you should use to obtain the desired information.